# Shell : How to extract the first occurence based on the first word of each lines?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a log file recording specific actions where the "first word" is the ID of the action, and I'd want to extract from it the first occurence of each ID so I can display the first action of each ID.

I'm not sure I'm quite clear, so let's say I have a file monitoring the actions of a bunch of people and that gets updated everytime someone does something :

> Alice ate an apple 
> Eve fell asleep 
> Bob watched TV 
> Bob sat on a chair 
> Alice went to the kitchen 
> Dave drank coffee 
> Carol bought a car 
> Eve fed the cat 
> Eve took out the trash 
> Dave took a shower 
> Bob washed the dishes 
> Alice read a book 
> Carol played the piano 
> ...

Let's say I want to see what is the first action done by each people, so the desired output would be :

> Alice ate an apple 
> Eve fell asleep 
> Bob watched TV 
> Dave drank coffee 
> Carol bought a car

I tried some conbinations of uniq and grep but there is a problem : To use the uniq command I would need to sort the lines first which defeat my purpose to get the first occurence (Example here, "Eve fed the cat" will come before "Eve fell asleep")

Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Thank you all for taking the time to read me.

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, this is highly encouraged on SO(not my downvote btw). thank you.

Comment: Sorry for that, I was afraid it would be TMI to provide non working code :) but I understand the reason, I'll fill it up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With awk this is simple:

```
$ awk '++arr[$1]==1' file
```

Prints:

```
Alice ate an apple 
Eve fell asleep 
Bob watched TV 
Dave drank coffee 
Carol bought a car
```

Works this way:

```
awk '++arr[$1]==1' file
        ^           arr is an associative array with key/value combo
      ^             when created with $1 key (the first col) val is 0
      ^             ++before adds 1 before return value         
               ^    equal to
                 ^  1 meaning first time seen
    ^           ^   if this resolve true (col 1 seen first time) print
```

You can do this with other shell tools (Bash, Ruby, Perl, Python, etc.) but almost all easy solutions will use that tools version of an associative array that counts the number of times X has been seen.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Not only you gave me a solution, but also a complete explanation of the command used ! I've never seen this use of awk before, I'm sure adapting this formula will be very useful in the future ! Thanks again !

Comment: Among the many reasons that `awk` is wonderful is that it is well documented. If you want to learn more, the definitive guide is Effective Awk Programming by Arnold D Robbins. [freely available](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatic [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '!seen[$1]++' file
```

This uses an associative array and the postfix increment operator to add the first field, $1, into an array called 'seen'. The value is zero the first time the key is encountered, so it can just be negated to return true the first time the key is seen.